# PHP upload server reset error

Tags: php, file-upload

This is my script. If i try to upload a image which is just 100kb am getting connection reset error.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploadtest/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed `upload_max_filesize`,`post_max_size`,`max_input_time`,`memory_limit` and `LimitRequestBody`. Nothing helps.

- upload_max_filesize: 240M
- memory_limit: 2000M
- post_max_size:128M
- max_input_time: 300000
- LimitRequestBody 102400

[image]

What might be the issue?

Comment: Check where php tries to save the file, what the tmp directory is and if it is accessible. Apart from that an error code and the upload size are available in `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]`.

Comment: Check php error logs and paste it here please.

Comment: folder permissions are  fine. it's 777. There is nothing logged in error log. Both in apache error_log and php error log that's the reason am not able to get the problem.